# FScalendar customisation

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I am new to programming, I am using FScalendar and I want to change days name into two alphabets i.e. (SU,MO,TU.....), and I want to remove the gaps between cells?

I have tried in given area but not found the solution:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) FSCalendarAppearance *appearance;`

I have attached image for reference in which gaps are visible clearly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mxMg.png)

Does this code need to be changed to get zero gap between cells???????

```
// Calculate item widths and lefts
    free(self.widths);
    self.widths = ({
        NSInteger columnCount = 7;
        size_t columnSize = sizeof(CGFloat)*columnCount;
        CGFloat *widths = malloc(columnSize);
        CGFloat contentWidth = self.collectionView.fs_width - self.sectionInsets.left - self.sectionInsets.right;
        FSCalendarSliceCake(contentWidth, columnCount, widths);
        widths;
    });

    free(self.lefts);
    self.lefts = ({
        NSInteger columnCount = 7;
        size_t columnSize = sizeof(CGFloat)*columnCount;
        CGFloat *lefts = malloc(columnSize);
        lefts[0] = self.sectionInsets.left;
        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) {
            lefts[i] = lefts[i-1] + self.widths[i-1];
        }
        lefts;
    });

    // Calculate item heights and tops
    free(self.heights);
    self.heights = ({
        NSInteger rowCount = self.calendar.transitionCoordinator.representingScope == FSCalendarScopeWeek ? 1 : 6;
        size_t rowSize = sizeof(CGFloat)*rowCount;
        CGFloat *heights = malloc(rowSize);
        if (!self.calendar.floatingMode) {
            CGFloat contentHeight = self.collectionView.fs_height - self.sectionInsets.top - self.sectionInsets.bottom;
            FSCalendarSliceCake(contentHeight, rowCount, heights);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                heights[i] = self.estimatedItemSize.height;
            }
        }
        heights;
    });

    free(self.tops);
    self.tops = ({
        NSInteger rowCount = self.calendar.transitionCoordinator.representingScope == FSCalendarScopeWeek ? 1 : 6;
        size_t rowSize = sizeof(CGFloat)*rowCount;
        CGFloat *tops = malloc(rowSize);
        tops[0] = self.sectionInsets.top;
        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            tops[i] = tops[i-1] + self.heights[i-1];
        }
        tops;
    });
```

source file ------>.   FSCalendarCollectionViewLayout.m

Comment: Please share more code for better explanation

Comment: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/167

Comment: @teja_D.....this is used to get single character heading, even it can be applied from interface also........

Answer (score 1):

[image] You can do this by adding a subview in fscalendar for weekDays. I ADDED SINGLE LETTER BUT YOU CAN ADD according to your requirements.
 1- create View[image]

2- [image]

3-

```
let week_days_view = weekDaysView.instanceFromNib() as! weekDaysView
    week_days_view.frame = self.fsCalendar.calendarWeekdayView.frame
    self.fsCalendar.calendarWeekdayView.addSubview(week_days_view)
```

Comment: @Ayaz........I did same thing to add pre month ban and next month btn, but this I want by changing in fscalendar library. Thanks for support.

Comment: than what is issue?

Comment: @ABTech you can see new added picture first Mo

Answer (score 0):

@ABTech Regarding this `I want to change days name into two alphabets i.e. (SU,MO,TU.....)`, Try with modification on `FSCalendarWeekdayView.m file` on it's `- (void)configureAppearance method` on `FSCalendar library`.[In Swift check here](https://www.agnosticdev.com/content/how-get-first-or-last-characters-string-swift-4)

```
NSString * str = [weekdaySymbols[index] uppercaseString];
label.text = [str substringToIndex:2];
```

And Regarding this `I want to remove the gaps between cells?`, Try this like below, Yes you need to try this `@property (weak, nonatomic) FSCalendarAppearance *appearance;`

```
    calendar.appearance.titleOffset = CGPoint.init(x: -50, y: 0.0)
    calendar.appearance.eventOffset = CGPoint.init(x: -50, y: 0.0)
```

Comment: This given code is to change offset of dates text, if it is applied, it will change the position of text only. And due tot his some dates got hide also.

Comment: @ABTech Then you should be define a custom cell with your desired leading space between the cells and should be register like on that library on your source `calendar.register(YourCalendarCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`